# Is Proof method valid

Tags: proof-verification

So I am studying for an upcoming midterm, and I am practicing my proofs. I found an old test online, that states the following:

$| x + y | + | x − y |≥| x | + | y |, x, y∈R .$

I want to know if my proof or attempt is fair enough to prove it?

my attempt:

let x be any arbitrary number, and since the absolute value of a number is always positive or zero

then $|x| ≥ x  $  then $ |x+y| ≥ x+y  ≥ |x| ≥ x  $

(given that y is an element of the real number set) --->$|x+y|+|x| ≥ |x|+|y| +x ≥ |x|+|y| ≥ x+y ≥ x  $

and lastly $ |x+y| +|x-y| ≥  |x|+|y|+|x| ≥ |x|+|y|≥ x+y ≥ x   $

end proof.

Comment: $x+y$ need not be $\ge |x|$.

Comment: so my proof is not sound?

Comment: It is not sound. This is not the only place where in incorrect assertion is made. For example, next line, it is not necessarily true that $|x|+|y|+x\ge |x|+|y|$, since $x$ could be negative.

Comment: I see, thank you, well that's why attempting random problems now is useful to learn

Comment: hmmmmmmmm I do not

Comment: I wrote out a proof that does not use the Triangle Inequality. But the Triangle Inequality is very important, so it is better to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $s$ and $t$ are non-negative, then $s\ge t$ if and only if $s^2\ge t^2$. Now
$$(|x+y|+|x-y|)^2=2x^2+2y^2+2|x^2-y^2|\ge 2x^2+2y^2\tag{1}$$
and 
$$(|x|+|y|)^2=x^2+y^2+2|xy|.\tag{2}$$
So it is enough to show that $2x^2+2y^2\ge x^2+y^2+2|xy|$, or equivalently that $x^2+y^2\ge 2|xy|$.

But this last inequality  is clear, for $x^2+y^2-2|xy|=(|x|-|y|)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

No, for example the step $x+y\ge |x|$ is not true, the counter example would be if $x+y<0$. Then there's more errors further down, but it's hard to tell which are a consequence of the first error and which are new errors, but for example the step $|x|+|y|+x\ge|x|+|y|$ definitely looks odd and the step $x+y\ge x$.

Finally it's not nice to keep irrelevant parts in the proof. For example the last step $|x+y|+|x-y|\ge...\ge|x|+|y|\ge...$ everything to the right of $|x|+|y|\ge$ is irrelevant (you was only to proove that $|x+y|+|x-y|\ge|x|+|y|$ - never forget what you're about to prove).

What you **could** do if you want to prove it using brute force is to divide it into the cases where the $x$, $y$, $x-y$ and $x+y$ are each positive or negative - there 16 combinations, some of which are impossible (you probably see those). It's a tedious way, but given you don't find any other way it's a possibility.

An easier way would be to use the triangle inequality:

$$|x+y| + |x-y| \ge |x+y+x-y| = |2x|$$

and then use this to prove it if $|x|\ge|y|$. How you us it for the case $|x|\le|y|$ you maybe can figure out yourself?

Comment: A simpler way is to apply $$|x+y| + |x-y| \ge |x+y+x-y| = |2x|$$  for $y$ directly  instead of $x$ .  Then  add the  two inequalities and the result directly  follows .

Comment: @Nizar Yes, that's what I pointed out as an easier way;)

Answer (score 0):

we have for any $x$ and $y$ (using triangle inequality)
$$|x+y| + |x-y| \ge |x+y+x-y| = |2x|$$
and $$|x+y| + |y-x| \ge |x+y-x+y| = |2y|$$
Adding up we get   $$2(|x+y| + |x-y| )\ge |2x|+ |2y| $$
hence  $$|x+y| + |x-y| \ge |x|+ |y| $$